# Merge object data with same date

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array I need help with.

```
let test = [
{
  date: ["2021-11-09", "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-10"],
  amount: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 2],
}];
```

How can I merge the amounts that have the same date? I want the data to be returned as below:

```
date: ["2021-11-09", "2021-11-10"],
amount: [1, 3],
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is just a 'group by' by date from the `date` array, summing the elements at the same index in the `amount` array.

```js
let test = [
  {
    date: ['2021-11-09', '2021-11-09', '2021-11-10', '2021-11-10'],
    amount: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 2],
  },
];

const result = test.map(({ date, amount }) => {
  const grouped = date.reduce((a, d, i) => a.set(d, (a.get(d) ?? 0) + amount[i]), new Map());

  return {
    date: [...grouped.keys()],
    amount: [...grouped.values()],
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: awesome thank you so much. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You could do with `Array#map` and `Array#reduce`. Then iterate the date array  after that add the amount based in index of date array. `Array#reduce` return the object. So separate the date and amount use `Object#values` and `Object#keys`

```js
let test = [ { date: ["2021-11-09", "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-10"], amount: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 2], }];

const res = test.map(({date,amount})=> {
  const sumObj = date.reduce((acc,c,i)=>(acc[c] = (acc[c] || 0)+amount[i],acc),{})
  return ({date:Object.keys(sumObj),amount:Object.values(sumObj)})
})
  
console.log(res)
```

Comment: thank you Prasanth!

Answer (score 0):

This code it is very simple processes an array of `date` and `amount` pairs, combines the amounts for the same dates, and produces an object with unique dates and their corresponding total amounts.

```js
let test = [
  {
    date: ["2021-11-09", "2021-11-09", "2021-11-10", "2021-11-10"],
    amount: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 2],
  },
];

const mergedData = {
  date: [],
  amount: []
};

test[0].date.forEach((date, index) => {
  if (!mergedData.date.includes(date)) {
    mergedData.date.push(date);
    mergedData.amount.push(test[0].amount[index]);
  } else {
    const existingIndex = mergedData.date.indexOf(date);
    mergedData.amount[existingIndex] += test[0].amount[index];
  }
});

console.log(mergedData);
```